# Edit Meta information in Magento category search result pages

Tags: magento

In Magento, I would like to set category specific information on category search result pages.

For example, if I search for "mobile phones", the meta title of the search result page should say something like "Mobile phones". Currently it only shows default meta information because there is no specific area in the admin panel in which I can make these settings.

I know that in the admin panel, I can set meta information for category pages. I am wondering if I can do something in the XML files so when a particular category is searched, the search result page automatically shows whatever meta information is set for the corresponding category page.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you put in **Catalog>Manage Categories>Your Category>Meta Description** will show in most search results page as the description below the link. However Google and other search engines may generate their own meta descriptions to use instead of yours.

To change titles, just set the name, and also check **System>Configuration>Design>HTML Head** - You can add a prefix or suffix to all pages including the category pages.

Comment: The meta information is a requirement from my client. Even though it comes up nicely in Google search results, I still need to change it. As for the title, I know I can change the site-wide default title but I need to be able to change it on particular pages.

Comment: @SaveTheMage the title suffix set in System>Configuration>Design>HTML Head only appears to apply to pages (e.g. home page, login, etc) and cms pages. It doesn't appear to apply to categories. Is there a setting somewhere else for this?

Comment: For a title suffix per category, its probably best to just set it in the Meta data for the category. Go to Catalog>Manage Categories, click the category and change the name - this will also be the title - or you can specify the Page Title on that same page. You could also edit the category listing page to show the cms pages title suffix That help at all?